# What is the difference between a priority queue and a min / max heap?

Tags: queue, heap

I know how a min and max heap work but am confused about what a priority queue is and how it differs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

[Priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) is an abstract data type (an interface definition) that defines three operations: *is_empty*, *insert_with_priority*, and *pull_highest_priority_element*. The definition says what those functions are expected to do, but it doesn't say how it is to be implemented.

A [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) is one way to implement a priority queue. Its advantages are ease of implementation and that it is reasonably efficient. It's not necessarily the most efficient way to implement a priority queue (see below). Whereas a heap is definitely a priority queue, by no means is it true that a priority queue is a heap.

A heap typically implements more functionality than is required by a priority queue. For example, heaps commonly have a constructor that will build the internal data structure very quickly, without having to call the *insert* method for each item. Heap also commonly implements a *peek* method, that will return the first item, without removing it. Both of these functions are not part of the priority queue definition.

You could implement a priority queue with a simple unsorted list, but doing so would not be particularly efficient. Same with a sorted list. You could also use a balanced binary search tree, which will give you better performance than a list, but not as good as a binary heap.

There are many priority queue implementations that are called "heaps," but they share very little in common with the traditional binary heap. [Pairing heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap), for example, is theoretically more efficient than binary heap, as is [Fibonacci heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap). In practice, Pairing heap *is* more efficient, but Fibonacci heap isn't. And [Brodal queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brodal_queue) is proven to be maximally efficient theoretically, but it's difficult to implement and in practice much slower than other priority queue implementations.

You can also implement a priority queue with a [Skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). My experience is that a skip list priority queue is as fast as, and sometimes much faster than, a binary heap.

There are many different implementations of the priority queue data structure. You can find a partial list at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Variants.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same thing, just different names.

Priority queue is most efficiently implemented using a heap, and then it is a heap. One could argue i suppose that the priority queue could be implemented w/ other data structures (with less efficiency).

So realistically I will say they're the same.

Expect someone to be pedantic and say one is an abstract type, etc.

Comment: It's not at all true that heap is the most efficient implementation. There are many different priority queue implementations, all of which have their advantages and disadvantages, and some of which are better for particular applications. A binary heap is a good general solution, but there are more efficient alternatives. And since you identified your own error in calling them the same, I won't belabor the point.

Comment: What's going to be more efficient in  worth case in terms of dereferences than a heap without knowing the characteristics of the data (for example we could just use an array if we know that all priorities are all unique, don't care about memory?)

Comment: I've found that a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) priority queue is often much more efficient than a binary heap. Also, [pairing heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap) (which is not a traditional heap) is at fast or faster than binary heap, at least in my tests. Both of these do, on average, many fewer dereferences.